# Viewing one-to-many relationship as column titles

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I'm doing the following query

```
    SELECT 
        p.id
        ,q.name
        ,pa.result
    FROM
        postulant_answers as pa
    LEFT OUTER JOIN postulants as p ON (p.id = pa.postulant_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN questions as q ON (q.id = pa.question_id);
```

which show me the following result:

```
    +------+--------------+--------+
    | id   | name         | result |
    +------+--------------+--------+
    |    9 | Question 1   |     15 |
    |    9 | Question 2   |     70 |
    |    9 | Question 3   |     75 |
    |  591 | Question 1   |     15 |
    |  591 | Question 2   |     70 |
    |  591 | Question 3   |     75 |
```

But I need something more like:

```
    +------+------------+------------+------------+
    | id   | Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 |
    +------+------------+------------+------------+
    |    9 |         15 |         70 |         75 |
    |  591 |         15 |         70 |         75 |
```

Can I do that in just one query?
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as a pivot but MySQL does not have a pivot function, so you can implement this using an aggregate function and a `CASE`:

```
SELECT p.id,
  max(case when q.name = 'Question 1' then pa.result end) Question1,
  max(case when q.name = 'Question 2' then pa.result end) Question2,
  max(case when q.name = 'Question 3' then pa.result end) Question3
FROM postulant_answers as pa
LEFT OUTER JOIN postulants as p 
  ON (p.id = pa.postulant_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN questions as q 
  ON (q.id = pa.question_id)
group by p.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4071/2)

Result:

```
|  ID | QUESTION1 | QUESTION2 | QUESTION3 |
-------------------------------------------
|   9 |        15 |        70 |        75 |
| 591 |        15 |        70 |        75 |
```

The above works great if you have a known number of questions but if the number of questions is unknown then you can use a prepared statement, similar to this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when q.name = ''',
      q.name,
      ''' then pa.result end) AS ',
      replace(name, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM questions;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT p.id, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM postulant_answers as pa
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN postulants as p 
                    ON (p.id = pa.postulant_id)
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN questions as q 
                    ON (q.id = pa.question_id)
                  group by p.id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4071/3)

Comment: http://datacharmer.org/downloads/pivot_tables_mysql_5.pdf This PDF seems to give a lot of good, easy-to-follow examples of your options.

Comment: @bluefeet But what if my Questions are variable. I just give 3 for the example, but in the real case there are about 100 different questions and I would prefer to write something which generate each column dinamically rather than write 100 times `max(case...`, or is my only choice?

Comment: @AlterLagos see my edit, you can use a prepared statement to generate the list dynamically

Comment: @bluefeet I'm having a problem with `GROUP_CONCAT` because is truncating the result for no more than 1024 bytes. Any clue?

Comment: @AlterLagos you will have to expand the session value see this link -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat